# How can I access the default JDT completion proposals in a custom Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin, that has the functionallity of auto completion (the thing when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).
Generally, I know how it works, I made a completion for my own proposals.

But the problem is, that my boss want me to make a completion the same as is in eclipse already. For example if I type "Str", or "org" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I want to have a completion lists from Java, for example for "Str" a "String", for "org" "org.eclipse...." + a long list. So I need to compute proposals for packages and for classes, just like in Eclipse's JDT editor.

I know that may sound stupid, making it the same as already is, but I need this solution.

Has anyone done a similar thing earlier? Which class do I need to implement?  What changes do I need to make (plugin.xml?)?

Comment: Is your problem showing the proposals, or generating them?

Comment: I can show my proposals which I compute. I know how it works, but i can't generate/display default Java proposals. I simply donno how, but I know this is somehow possible :)

Comment: I don't know any details, but I suppose you somehow can look how the JDT does this, and access the same methods (or copy them, if you don't want to be dependent on the JDT plugins). (I edited the question title, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

Try org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCollector. There's an example on how to use it in the class' Javadoc.